# Is it possible to stop or redirect auto reply messages when sending emails out with Exact Target?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign, redirect

We send quite a lot of campaigns out everyday using Exact Target and the out of office / auto replies can fill an inbox very quickly. Is there a way to stop us receiving the automatic responses / re-divert them to another set up mail box for this purpose alone?

Kind Regards
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup Reply Mail Management to delete auto-replies and out-of-office replies. Refer to [the RMM documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/) which explains:

> When you configure RMM, you indicate how you want the reply rules to identify and respond to the replies that subscribers send:
>
> **Delete auto-replies and out-of-office replies.** If you select Yes, RMM deletes messages that contain any of the following terms in the message header, email Subject line, email From address, or the first 200 characters of the email body. If you select No, RMM forwards the messages to a forwarding address that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

**RMM Software Features and Benefits**

Up-to-the-second inventory of all managed devices in a single console

Easily configure endpoint security policies using the intuitive policies interface

Automatically create a service desk ticket if an endpoint falls out of compliance with its policy

Panoramic, real time information allows you to make better, more informed decisions

Multiple plug-ins allow you to observe running processes, services, active connections, auto-run applications, browser extensions, system restore points and more

Ability to run system and registry clean operations with a single click

Easily transfer files between your computer and endpoint machines

One MSP - [RMM](https://one.comodo.com) - Administrator Guide

Built-in RDP software allows you to access client machines directly from the management console

Run commands in multiple interpreter languages

Craft and execute procedures which can be used and re-used for common endpoint tasks

Advanced Procedure Wizard allows you to create and run commands in sequential order

Remotely restart and shutdown endpoints with the integrated power manager

Agent runs as a service, the endpoint need not be logged in

Patent pending rescue option allows administrators to restart endpoints in rescue mode

Comment: Quoting the documentation doesn't particularly provide an answer. Perhaps there's more you wanted to say as to why this is relevant to the question?